# A "No such file or directory" error occurs with the appscan.sh command

Tags: linux, ibm-cloud, bluemix-app-scan

I am trying to generate .irx file using SAClientUtil.6.0.1142 in a Linux machine. However, when I execute the `appscan.sh prepare -c <config file> -d <destination file>` command, it throws an error like:

> SAClientUtil.6.0.1142/bin/appscan.sh: line 75:
>   /opt/SAClientUtil.6.0.1142/bin/..//jre/bin/java: No such file or
>   directory

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like either you don't have a JRE installed on your linux system or it is not installed at path `/opt/SAClientUtil.6.0.1142/bin/..//jre/bin/java`.

`java -version` will tell you the java version if its installed, and `which java` will tell you the location where it is installed.

Comment: output for java -version command ..../usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 and i have done echo $PATH and this is output ..../usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: @Mounika you will have to edit the appscan.sh script with correct path for java so that it uses the one you get from `which java` command instead of `/opt/SAClientUtil.6.0.1142/bin/..//jre/bin/java`

Comment: Thank you Lohit Gupta.It is resolved. i have installed these dependencies..glibc.i686
libgcc.i686
libstdc++.i686....and it is working fine